# Facebook API Receiving Postback Messages but not Raw Text Messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Currently, if I send a message to my chatbot through the persistent menu, I get a POST request (ngrok indicates this) containing the postback. However, when I send a raw text message through typing, the message is not marked as sent and my bot does not get a POST request. My bot occasionally receives raw text messages hours to days later, however the message is always the same and is repeated multiple times.